# How to return the position of object by names?

Tags: java, collections

I have a method that count the position of an Item by comparing others Item names, but I wanted to know if there were a simplier way to do it ?

```
  //  arr.get(0) : Item0:"nameA"
  //  arr.get(1) : Item1:"nameB"
  //  arr.get(2) : Item2:"nameB"
  //  arr.get(3) : Item3:"nameB"
  //  arr.get(4) : Item4:"nameC"
  //  arr.get(5) : Item5:"nameC"
  //  arr.get(6) : Item6:"nameB"

  //  If I set (arr, Item2) : should return 2 ("nameB")
  //  If I set (arr, Item6) : should return 4 ("nameB")
  //  If I set (arr, Item5) : should return 2 ("nameC")

public int positionOfItemByName(Item[] array, Item item) {
    int cpt = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (array[i].name().indexOf( item.name() ) == -1) continue;
        cpt++;
        if (array[i] == item) break;
    }
    return cpt;
}
```

Thanks !

Comment: Asuming that `name` is just a string; why checking equality by `.indexOf` rather than `equals`?

Comment: Your solution would return 0 for an element that isn't in the array. I recommend that you return -1 in this case, because 0 is a valid return value if `item` is in position 0 of `arr`

Comment: I didn't know about equals ^^ Do you think there is way using Collections or something ?

Comment: @alexino2  - I've already provided a solution using Stream API. Did you get a chance to check that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your requirement, the method name, `positionOfItemByName` doesn't sound appropriate. From an execution perspective, it doesn't matter which name you choose. However, the name should be as self-descriptive as possible.

Given below is the logic to meet your requirement:

```
public static int countOfItemByNameAndPosition(Item[] array, Item item) {
    List<Item> arr = new ArrayList<Item>(Arrays.asList(array));
    int cpt = 0;
    int index = arr.indexOf(item);
    if (index != -1) {
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.size() && i <= index; i++) {
            if (arr.get(i).name.equals(item.name)) {
                cpt++;
            }
        }
    }
    return cpt;
}
```

## Demo

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

class Item {
    String name;

    public Item(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Item [name=" + name + "]";
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Item item0 = new Item("nameA");
        Item item1 = new Item("nameB");
        Item item2 = new Item("nameB");
        Item item3 = new Item("nameB");
        Item item4 = new Item("nameC");
        Item item5 = new Item("nameC");
        Item item6 = new Item("nameB");

        Item[] array = { item0, item1, item2, item3, item4, item5, item6 };
        System.out.println(countOfItemByNameAndPosition(array, item2));
        System.out.println(countOfItemByNameAndPosition(array, item6));
        System.out.println(countOfItemByNameAndPosition(array, item5));
    }

    public static int countOfItemByNameAndPosition(Item[] array, Item item) {
        List<Item> arr = new ArrayList<Item>(Arrays.asList(array));
        int cpt = 0;
        int index = arr.indexOf(item);
        if (index != -1) {
            for (int i = 0; i < arr.size() && i <= index; i++) {
                if (arr.get(i).name.equals(item.name)) {
                    cpt++;
                }
            }
        }
        return cpt;
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2
4
2
```

## Using Stream API:

```
public static int countOfItemByNameAndPosition(Item[] array, Item item) {
    List<Item> arr = new ArrayList<Item>(Arrays.asList(array));
    return (int) IntStream.range(0, arr.indexOf(item)+1).filter(i -> item.name.equals(arr.get(i).name)).count();
}
```

## Demo

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

class Item {
    String name;

    public Item(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Item [name=" + name + "]";
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Item item0 = new Item("nameA");
        Item item1 = new Item("nameB");
        Item item2 = new Item("nameB");
        Item item3 = new Item("nameB");
        Item item4 = new Item("nameC");
        Item item5 = new Item("nameC");
        Item item6 = new Item("nameB");

        Item[] array = { item0, item1, item2, item3, item4, item5, item6 };
        System.out.println(countOfItemByNameAndPosition(array, item2));
        System.out.println(countOfItemByNameAndPosition(array, item6));
        System.out.println(countOfItemByNameAndPosition(array, item5));
    }

    public static int countOfItemByNameAndPosition(Item[] array, Item item) {
        List<Item> arr = new ArrayList<Item>(Arrays.asList(array));
        return (int) IntStream.range(0, arr.indexOf(item) + 1).filter(i -> item.name.equals(arr.get(i).name)).count();
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2
4
2
```

Feel free to comment in case of any doubt/issue.

Comment: thanks for answer, i'm really bad at naming, should be getIndexOfItemByName() . A more simplier way would have have been (but i don't know how collections works !) : 
arrayNameB = Collections.singleton("nameB");
index = arrayNameB.get(item4); ...........

Comment: Yep that is it, sorry, I edit again, i will reedit, don't touch anything ! that the answer i was looking for

Comment: Thanks for you time, i'll start looking at Stream API more closly, there are so much frameworks (if we call it that way?) that i'm a bit lost :/ When i first saw you answer, i was confused with the (i <= index) but make all senses now ^^

Comment: Also, I don't know if i must edit the question again to feet your perfect answer ? I did edit  ArrayList<Item> (in arguments) to Item[], thinking it would be simplier to understand :/ What do you think ?

Comment: I've rolled back your question to a previous version which was quite clear. Wish you success!

Comment: Thanks ! I'm so bad asking questions :/ but really didn't find this one on Google after hours of research. Don't hesite to edit more stuff to make the question more clear for other users that could have the same problem haha.

Comment: An other dumb question : should this method be always static ? I was thinking to put in an ArrayItem class...

Comment: It doesn't need to be `static` if you call it using an instance e.g. if you want to call it like `Main m = new Main(); System.out.println(m.countOfItemByNameAndPosition(array, item2));`. However, if you call it directly (i.e. without using an instance) from a `static` method e.g. `main`, it must be `static`.

Comment: (sorry for delete) i didn't understand what you answered, i feel so old :/ Always told me that static was bad :/

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is. First, you can just return `i`, the variable `cpt` is redundant. Second, you don't need two checks inside the loop. You can combine both with the [`String#equals(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) method that checks the equality of two strings. Return `-1` if the name cannot be found. Negative numbers are not valid indices of arrays/collections, thus good values to say *"not found"*.

```java
public int positionOfSameName(ArrayList<Item> arr, Item item) {
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++) {
        if (arr.get(i).name().equals(item.name()) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

---

*Edit:* After your clarification that you want to count the occurrences of the given name in the given array, you need to work with an additional variable.

```java
public int positionOfSameName(ArrayList<Item> arr, Item item) {
    int counter = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++) {
        if (arr.get(i).name().equals(item.name()) {
            counter++;
        }
    }
    return counter;
}
```

*FYI:* You should consider changing the name of the method. As it is right now it's not doing what it *says* by its name.

Comment: yes but it returns the first name i get from list no ?

Comment: @alexino2 For clarification; do you want to know the *position* of an existing name or do you want to know *how many* times a name occurs in the list?

Comment: @alexino2 No, it will iterate over the list and when it finds the item you want it will return the current loop counter which is the index of your item in the array.

Comment: For example : Item1 : "nameA", item2 :" nameB", item3 : "nameB", item4 : "nameB"
I put item4 in argument, I would like it to return 3, not 2 ^^ the equals do that ? Sorry i don't know how it really works...

Comment: @alexino2 In this case you want to check the equality of the *object*, i.e. check the equality of the references. I'll add this to my answer.

Comment: @akuzminykh your edit return me 4, not 3...
To be simple, i want get the position in all "nameB" : if i put item2, it return 1, if i put item3 it return 2 and item4 return 3 ^^

Comment: @alexino2 This is exactly what I mentioned in my first comment: "[...] or do you want to know how many times a name occurs in the list?". Why not just saying "yes"? Anyways, I'll edit my answer a final time to include that.

Comment: I'm sorry, my english is bad and translate is difficult :'(, i don't know all terms in coding and i'm a beginner too.

Comment: @alexino2 This is okay. :-) Now please check if the solution answers your question and consider accepting it, so other people won't need to read everything to find out if they should answer.

Comment: I also heard about a Collections singleton ("nameB") and maybe a index of item2 in this collection could work ?

Comment: @akuzminykh you edit will count all "NameB" not give the position of item2:"NameB" in all NameB.....

Comment: I edited again, The question was : is there Collections or something to it ?

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to create equals method to your class that will look like

```
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if(!(o instanceof Item))
        return false;
    Item other = (Item)o;
    //you can change it to any compare method you want
    return other.name.equals(this.name);
}
```

And then just use the function indexOf and it will use your method to compare.

Comment: I'll edit the question, maybe it will be more simple to understand.